# How to add swap space on fedora?

Tags: linux, memory, fedora, swap

I want to add swap space on my machine running Fedora. Searching on this raised questions:

1. I found [this 2016 post](https://superuser.com/questions/1024064/change-swap-file-size-fedora-23) showing a method to do it, but a comment says changing the swap could result in boot issues. Is it safe to follow that method ?
2. [Fedora's doc](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/workstation-docs/disk-config/) says it replaced swap with "an emulated drive that uses RAM for its storage". This got me very confused because I thought the whole point of swap was to use the disk memory when the RAM is full.

Anyway, here is my use case: I have a fairly recent laptop with 24GB RAM, and a 1TB SSD which is 5% full. I want to try running some of the new LLaMA-based LLMs, but they need easily tens of GBs of RAM to load the models. Since I have plenty of free space in my SSD I want to turn ~200GB of it into swap space and be able to load the models.

Here is the result of running `lsblk` (I removed 30 or so lines of snaps):

```
loop0    7:0    0   104M  1 loop /var/lib/snapd/snap/authy/18
loop1    7:1    0     4K  1 loop /var/lib/snapd/snap/bare/5
...
loop34   7:34   0 320.4M  1 loop /var/lib/snapd/snap/vlc/3078
zram0  252:0    0     8G  0 disk [SWAP]
nvme0n1
       259:0    0 953.9G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1
│      259:1    0   260M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2
│      259:2    0    16M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p3
│      259:3    0 269.1G  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p4
│      259:4    0   959M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p5
│      259:5    0     1G  0 part /boot
└─nvme0n1p6
       259:6    0 634.8G  0 part /home
                                 /
```

Comment: What is the partition(s) on this SSD, filesystem, do you use LVM?

Comment: Ad. 2. "The zram drive is compressed", this is the point. When the RAM is nearly full, the OS takes uncompressed data from RAM and places in ZRAM as compressed. This way some RAM is freed and ready to take more data (compressed or not).

Comment: I have my doubts RAM compression will help much. Moreover maybe these models are already compressed.

Comment: @RomeoNinov I have Windows in dual boot, an ext4 `/boot` partition, and the Fedora `/` partition is btrfs. About LVM I am not sure , there are files in /etc/lvm/ but running `pvdisplay` or `lvscan` don't show anything

Comment: From linux exec `lsblk` and add the result to the question

Comment: @RomeoNinov I did `lsblk` and pasted the result

Comment: Do you have 200GB free in `/home`?

Comment: @RomeoNinov yes, I only used 50GB so there is ample free space

Answer (score 4):

### What worked

Following Kamil's comment I followed the [instructions here](https://superuser.com/questions/1067150/how-to-create-swapfile-on-ssd-disk-with-btrfs/1442752#1442752).

### First try

I partially solved my problem. The method in (1) didn't work, seemingly because btrfs does not allow swap files. So I followed what I read [here](https://discussion.fedoraproject.org/t/how-to-modify-swap-space-on-fedora-36-btrfs/77091), and created  a file `/etc/systemd/zram-generator.conf` with the following content:

```
[zram0]
zram-size = 100000
```

After a reboot I now have around 100 G of zram:

```
$ zramctl
NAME       ALGORITHM DISKSIZE  DATA  COMPR TOTAL STREAMS MOUNTPOINT
/dev/zram0 lzo-rle      97.7G  3.4G 931.5M  1.2G      12 [SWAP]
```

However when trying to run the LLMs, the swap memory use reached up to 24GB only and then it plateaued and the program was killed by lack of memory. At this point I'm not sure whether the issues lies with zram itself or the program I try to run...

Comment: "seemingly because btrfs does not allow swap files" – This [used to be an issue](https://superuser.com/a/1067213/432690). Nowadays you can use a swap file on btrfs but [it requires special setup](https://superuser.com/a/1442752/432690).

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did and worked for me. here is the output of `lsblk`:

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sda           8:0    0   7.3T  0 disk 
├─sda1        8:1    0    16M  0 part 
└─sda2        8:2    0   7.3T  0 part /run/media/ef/Storage
zram0       252:0    0     8G  0 disk [SWAP]
nvme0n1     259:0    0   1.8T  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0    16M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0 834.7G  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0   614M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p4 259:4    0   100M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p5 259:5    0     1G  0 part /boot
└─nvme0n1p6 259:6    0     1T  0 part /home
```

and here is output of $ swapon -s

```
Filename                Type        Size        Used        Priority
/dev/zram0              partition   8388604     1935420     100
```

Here are the steps I followed:

```
$ sudo touch /swapfile
$ sudo chattr +C /swapfile 
$ sudo lsattr /swapfile
$ sudo fallocate -l 200G /swapfile
$ sudo lsattr /swapfile
$ sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
$ sudo lsattr /swapfile  # make sure you see the letter C in the results: ---------------C------ /swapfile
$ sudo mkswap /swapfile # output example: Setting up swapspace version 1, size = 200 GiB (214748360704 bytes)
$ sudo mkswap /swapfile # output example: Setting up swapspace version 1, size = 200 GiB (214748360704 bytes)
                                          no label, UUID=98a6c4a0-ec8d-4afb-90af-6162e83d30b3
$ sudo swapon /swapfile
$ vim /etc/fstab
```

here I added one line at the end of `/etc/fstab`:

```
/swapfile swap swap defaults 0 0
```

That's it. Now you can see it shows up:

```
$ sudo swapon -s
NAME       TYPE      SIZE USED PRIO
/dev/zram0 partition   8G 1.8G  100
/swapfile  file      200G   0B   -2
```

I tested it and it works for reading huge files.
resources that helped:

- https://superuser.com/a/1411462/432690
- https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Adding_and_Managing_Fedora_Swap_Space